# Issue with synchronous FIFO [VHDL]

Tags: vhdl, fifo, synthesis

I am trying to implement a FIFO from Fpga Prototyping By Vhdl Examples (Wiley) and I am having some issues. The first poped data is actually the second data pushed. It seems to be skipping one slot of the FIFO.

Here is the code:

```
library IEEE;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL; 
use WORK.my_pkg.ALL;

entity Fifo is      
   Port(
        clk             : in  STD_LOGIC;
      rst_n             : in  STD_LOGIC;
        -- DATA 
      push_data_i   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (FIFO_WIDTH-1 downto 0);     -- Data IN.
        pop_data_o      : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (FIFO_WIDTH-1 downto 0);     -- Data out.
        -- CONTROL
      push_valid_i  : in  STD_LOGIC;                                                -- 1 to write push_data_i into the FIFO.
      pop_grant_i   : in  STD_LOGIC;                                                -- 1 to read from the FIFO.
        -- STATUS
        push_grant_o    : out STD_LOGIC;                                                -- 0 when full. To write push_grant_o=1 and push_valid_i=1.
        pop_valid_o     : out STD_LOGIC                                             -- 1 where there is data available in the FIFO.
        );
end Fifo;

architecture Behavioral of Fifo is
    type reg_type is array (2**FIFO_DEPTH-1 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (FIFO_WIDTH-1 downto 0);              -- FIFO_WIDTH x FIFO_DEPTH 2D-array.
    signal array_reg : reg_type;                                                                                                    -- FIFO itself. Data is stored here.
    signal write_ptr_reg, write_ptr_next, write_ptr_succ : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (FIFO_DEPTH-1 downto 0);        -- Write control registers.
    signal read_ptr_reg, read_ptr_next, read_ptr_succ : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (FIFO_DEPTH-1 downto 0);           -- Read control registers.
    signal full_reg, full_next  : STD_LOGIC := '0';                                                                         -- Status registers
    signal empty_reg, empty_next : STD_LOGIC := '1';                                                                        -- Status registers
    signal operation : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0) := "00";                                                           -- Operation 2 bit array 
    signal wr_en: STD_LOGIC;                                                                                                        -- Write possible register.

    begin
        -- ** PUSH & POP PORTS (data) ** --
        process(clk, rst_n)
        begin
            if(rst_n='0') then
                array_reg <= (others=>(others=>'0'));                                       -- Sets the entire array_reg (2D-array) to 0.
                write_ptr_reg <= (others=>'0'); -- Resets all write registers (to 0).
                read_ptr_reg <= (others=>'0');  -- Resets all read registers (to 0).
                full_reg <= '0';                        -- Full register is set to 0 as FIFO is not FULL.
                empty_reg <= '1';                       -- Empty register is set to 1 as FIFO is empty.
            elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then                                              -- Rising edge of the clock.
                if (wr_en='1') then
                    array_reg(to_integer(unsigned(write_ptr_reg))) <= push_data_i;  -- It writes the incoming data (push_data_i) to the corresponding position in the FIFO.
                                                                                                        -- It expects an intiger as the position in the array. Therefore the 'to_intiger' function.
                end if;
                write_ptr_reg <= write_ptr_next;    -- Current write position becomes the next one on clock event.
                read_ptr_reg <= read_ptr_next;  -- Current read position becomes the next one on clock event.
                full_reg <= full_next;              -- Current full position becomes the next one on clock event.
                empty_reg <= empty_next;            -- Current empty position becomes the next one on clock event.
            end if;
        end process;
        -- Input port:
        wr_en <= push_valid_i and (not full_reg);   -- If FIFO is NOT full it is possible to write.
        -- Output port:
        -- It is done differently from the input port as the output data ('first-in', pointed by read_ptr_reg)has to be available all the time.
        pop_data_o <= array_reg(to_integer(unsigned(read_ptr_reg)));

        -- Successive values to read and write when requested.
        write_ptr_succ <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(write_ptr_reg)+1);
        read_ptr_succ <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(read_ptr_reg)+1);

        -- ** Events and register control  ** --
        operation <= (push_valid_i & pop_grant_i);  -- Concatenates the two control inputs for the 'case, when' statement.
        process(write_ptr_reg, write_ptr_succ, read_ptr_reg, read_ptr_succ,
                  operation, full_reg, empty_reg)
        begin
            write_ptr_next <= write_ptr_reg;        -- This four lines are to assure that the current state does not
            read_ptr_next <= read_ptr_reg;      -- change in case none of the case-when statements happen.
            full_next <= full_reg;
            empty_next <= empty_reg;
            case operation is
                when "00" =>                                            -- Not write (push) or read (pop).
                when "01" =>                                            -- Read.
                    if(empty_reg /= '1') then                       -- If FIFO is NOT empty, it can be read.
                        read_ptr_next <= read_ptr_succ;         -- It points to the successive position to read.
                        full_next <= '0';                               -- As one position is read, FIFO will NOT be full.
                        if(read_ptr_succ=write_ptr_reg) then    -- Read 'reached' write. So the FIFO will be EMPTY.
                            empty_next <= '1';
                        end if;
                    end if;
                when "10" =>                                            -- Write.
                    if(full_reg /='1') then                         -- If FIFO is NOT full, it can be written.
                        write_ptr_next <= write_ptr_succ;
                        empty_next <= '0';                          -- The FIFO is written, so it will NOT be empty.
                        if(write_ptr_succ=read_ptr_reg) then    -- Write 'reached' read, so the FIFO will be full.
                            full_next <= '1';
                        end if;
                    end if;
                when others =>                                      -- Write and Read at the same time.
                    write_ptr_next <= write_ptr_succ;
                    read_ptr_next <= read_ptr_succ;
                end case;
        end process;

        -- Output STATUS
        push_grant_o <= not full_reg;
        pop_valid_o <= not empty_reg;
end Behavioral;
```

my_pkg.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

--use IEEE.math_real."ceil";
--use IEEE.math_real."log2";

package my_pkg is
        -- ** This should be used if math_real library available. Otherwise comment lines 24 and 25. Uncomment line 27 ** --
        --constant SLOTS : positive := 4;               -- This values has to be a power of two (2, 4, 8, 16, etc).
        --constant FIFO_DEPTH   : positive := integer(ceil(log2(real(SLOTS))));

        constant FIFO_DEPTH : positive := 2;    -- The number of SLOTS of the FIFO will be 2^FIFO_DEPTH. In this case, 4 slots.
        constant DATA_WIDTH  : positive := 3;
        constant FIFO_WIDTH  : positive := DATA_WIDTH+1;    --DATAWIDTH=WIDTH+1bitParity
        constant PARITY     : bit         := '0';   -- EVEN or ODD.
        constant PARITY_BIT : bit         := '0';   -- LSB or MSB.
end my_pkg;
```

Here is the testbench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY Fifo_testbench IS
END Fifo_testbench;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF Fifo_testbench IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT Fifo
    PORT(
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         rst_n : IN  std_logic;
         push_data_i : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         pop_data_o : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         push_valid_i : IN  std_logic;
         pop_grant_i : IN  std_logic;
         push_grant_o : OUT  std_logic;
         pop_valid_o : OUT  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal rst_n : std_logic := '0';
   signal push_data_i : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal push_valid_i : std_logic := '0';
   signal pop_grant_i : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal pop_data_o : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   signal push_grant_o : std_logic;
   signal pop_valid_o : std_logic;

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: Fifo PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
          rst_n => rst_n,
          push_data_i => push_data_i,
          pop_data_o => pop_data_o,
          push_valid_i => push_valid_i,
          pop_grant_i => pop_grant_i,
          push_grant_o => push_grant_o,
          pop_valid_o => pop_valid_o
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 20 ns;   

        rst_n <= '1';

        push_valid_i <= '1';
        push_data_i <= "1001";
        wait for clk_period;
        push_data_i <= "1010";
        wait for clk_period;
        push_data_i <= "1011";
        wait for clk_period;
        push_data_i <= "1100";
        wait for clk_period;
        push_data_i <= "1101";
        wait for clk_period;
        push_valid_i <= '0';


      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

And here the simulation:
[image: Simulation]

The idea is that all the 4 initial values (1001, 1010, 1011 and 1100) are pushed into the FIFO as push_grant_i is enable and the FIFO is not full. For the 5th value (1101) the FIFO cannot push it as it is full. It seems to be working ok, but after the first rising edge of the clock (30ns in the simulation) when the first value (1001) has been pushed it is not on the output port (pop_data_o). In fact, it is the second value, so it skipped 1001.  pop_data_o should be updated only if pop_grant_i is 1.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you were to use the waveform display to peer into the unit under test you'd find that writes were going to the [wrong place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyvxg.png).

Comment: Yes, it is writing to the wrong place, but `array_reg(to_integer(unsigned(write_ptr_reg))) <= push_data_i;` seems fine as 'write_ptr_reg' does updates until a new value is pushed. I don't get why the first value isn't pushed to the first position of `array_reg`.

Comment: In the testbench stim_proc delay stimuli until after the clock edge, e.g. `wait for 21 ns;` instead of 20 ns. That does wonders for your [FIFO state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45P0E.png).

Comment: Oh wow, that seems to be the solution. Why is that? Because the reset condition changes at the same moment so at 20ns the system is still on reset?

Comment: You'll find that your stimuli were being updated in the delta cycle before they were being acted on.  It's an artifact of how your clk_process works and the asynchronous delay using a wait for. You could wait until the clock event instead, so the clock occurs one delta cycle (minimum) before stimuli are changed. You could likewise wait on clock events before every change in stimuli in your synchronous model. Time isn't precise in zero time models, where delta cycles have to be taken in to account as well.

Comment: Got it. Great explanation.

Comment: Last quick question so I don't open a new one. Is it possible to have a counter on the testbench or I should rather design an entire architecture with counters included?

Comment: You can have a counter in a process on the testbench.

Comment: Great, but the testbench would only be usefull if I want to inject stimulus to the architecture. It would not work to check the integrity of data for example, right? For that I would have to build a whole new architecture, instantiating the FIFO in it and there I should also include counters an some logic to increment the counters depending on the conditions I want, right?

Comment: Could I have another process in the testbench to count for example how many times the poped data is some value (i.e "1011")? Or for this I should write another HDL design and instantiate the FIFO in it? The last approach seems to be the better one, right?

Comment: You can operate that process off events on clk  (rising edge) when pop_valid. That can be anywhere you can access those plus pop_data_o. It's generally referred to as a monitor process.  Testbenches can be used for more than just providing stimuli. You'd need buckets for each monitored value big enough to hold as many events as can occur. You'd think integers (naturals) would likely be big enough for simulation.

Comment: So I declared `shared variable count: integer :=0;` and then in a monitor process I checked `if valid_o='1'`. This way I increment `count := count + 1;` if true. I checked for 4 clk_periods. If it is _true twice_ **count=10**, but if it is _true 3 times_, **count=11111**.

Comment: Without seeing the process, stimuli and possibly waveform without enough detail, they why isn't apparent. Qualified with rising_edge(clk)?  operation = "01" (read)? (Only count occurrences actually read).  Don't use shared variables and expect your code to port to -2008, where they are protected types accessed by methods. Use a signal.

Comment: A signal solved it. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: I have just found another issue. When the FIFO is FULL, the next risign clk there is data pushed and poped at the same time, it does not pushes the data. The full reg it is still 1, but as it is pushing and poping at the same time there should be able to pop and then push (in theory).

Comment: Solved it. It should be `operation <= (((not full_reg) and push_valid_i) & ((not empty_reg) and pop_grant_i));` rather than `operation <= ( push_valid_i &  pop_grant_i);`

Comment: You shouldn't be able to write to a full FIFO. Which is what your change looks to do. You're using way to many parentheses. `operation <= (not full_reg and push_valid_i) & (not empty_reg and pop_grant_i);` It's in knowing operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

There's a race condition in your testbench. I.e. you change push_data_i at the time of the clock edge. That would also not work in real-life as registers have setup- and hold times. You should use the same clock for the test bench as you use for the UUT. E.g.

```
-- Stimulus process
stim_proc: process
begin        
    -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
    wait for 100 ns;   
    rst_n <= '1';

    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    push_valid_i <= '1';
    push_data_i <= "1001";
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    push_data_i <= "1010";
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    push_data_i <= "1011";
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    push_data_i <= "1100";
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    push_data_i <= "1101";
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    push_valid_i <= '0';

    wait;
end process;
```